# What is the use of following files in the React and Redux app?

Tags: reactjs, redux

What is the use of below files in the REACT solution? How the flow is work's here?
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LK1vZ.png)

This one is in the root folder.

1, Epic.js:

```
import { combineEpics } from 'redux-observable';
import { values } from 'lodash';

import * as postsEpics from './posts/epics';

export default combineEpics(
  ...values(postsEpics)
);
```

Following are inside of the POST folder

1,Selector.js :

```
export function getParams(state) {
  return state.posts.params;
}

export function getPost(state, id) {
  return state.posts.byId[id];
}
```

2, reducer.js:

```
import Immutable from 'seamless-immutable';
import * as actionTypes from './actionTypes';

const initialState = Immutable({
  byId: {},
  params: {}
});

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.FETCH_ONE_SUCCESS:      
  }
};
```

3,Index.js:

```
import * as postsActions from './actionCreators';
import * as postsSelectors from './selectors';

export {
  postsActions,
  postsSelectors,
};
```

4,epic.js: API call is happening to here

```
export function fetchPost(action$) {
  return action$.ofType(actionTypes.FETCH_ONE)
    .map(action => action.payload)
    .switchMap(id => {
      return Observable.fromPromise(
        axios.get(`http://localhost:8081/posts/${id}`)
      ).map(res => postsActions.fetchPostSuccess(res.data));
    });
}
```

5, actionType.js: It looks like maintaining all API state constant in single file.

```
export const FETCH_ONE = 'posts/FETCH_ONE';
export const FETCH_ONE_SUCCESS = 'posts/FETCH_ONE_SUCCESS';
export const FETCH_COLLECTION = 'posts/FETCH_COLLECTION';
```

6,actionCreator.js: **what is the use of the action creator file**

```
import { keyBy } from 'lodash';
import * as actionTypes from './actionTypes';

export function fetchPost(payload) {
  return {type: actionTypes.FETCH_ONE, payload};
}

export function fetchPostSuccess(payload) {
  const byId = {[payload.id]: payload};
  return {type: actionTypes.FETCH_ONE_SUCCESS, payload: {byId}};
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This looks like file structure for typical redux application to me where

actionTypes -> contains constants for possible actions

actionCreator -> contains actions which would dispatch a action with type from one of the constants in actionTypes and payload which can be consumed by reducer.

reducer -> contains reducer which has initial state and logic to make changes to redux store based on action which is being received.

For more details you read the following article which explains creation of react-redux app.
https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/step-by-step-guide-to-building-react-redux-apps-using-mocks-48ca0f47f9a

Comment: Thanks for the link. What is the use of epics.js and selectors.js?

Comment: must be containing some component or logic i guess.

Comment: Can you give a small explanation of the files, I have modified the question?

Comment: @ksrider148 take a look at redux and you will get usage